Identifying one or two Tamil Rajinikanth movies
I remember two scenes (or rather sequences of scenes) which I think come from the same Tamil movie featuring the famous actor Rajnikanth, but it's possible that they come from two different Rajinikanth movies.
Scene 1 Rajinikanth is a school teacher or college professor, and in his class there is a student whose father is some big-shot, perhaps the headmaster or a big gang leader.  Everyone else shows great respect towards the student due to who his father is, but Rajinikanth treats the student like he's just an ordinary student, in fact I think he even humiliates the student in front of the class for doing something wrong.  So to get revenge, the student goes into the bathroom and bashes his own head into the mirror, and then accuses Rajinikanth of doing it.  Rajinikanth is forced to make a public apology to the student in front of the whole school.  He first makes the apology in English, but then he's told it's disrespectful to apologize in English, so he says it in Tamil: "Ennai Manichukungo."
Scene 2  The villain of the movie has done some kind of crime, but Rajinikanth doesn't have any evidence to prove it.  So he kidnaps one of the villain's henchman, and brings the henchman into a building that's been lit on fire, threatening to leave the henchman in the building unless the henchman tells the truth.  So the henchman tells the truth, and Rajinikanth records the confession on a tape recorder.  But then when the henchman gets back to the villain, the villain has the henchman's tongue cut out.  So then when the audio recording is played in court, the villain's lawyer tells the court that that can't be the henchman's voice on the tape, because as the lawyer demonstrates the henchman has no tongue.
Now as I said, it's possible that these are two entirely different movies; I may be conflating them because in both cases, Rajinikanth is in the right but a villain is able to make it seem like Rajinikanth is in the wrong.
One more thing: the movie that Scene 1 is from is not Dharmathin Thalaivan, even though that's also a movie featuring Rajinikanth as a professor.  Dharmathin Thalaivan is still a great movie though!

The movie related to the Scene 2 is Pandiyan from 1992. 
In this movie Rajinikanth's role is a police officer and gangster, so the Scene 1 and Scene 2 are not from the same movie.
The court scene is as follows:



The Scene 1, you are described is not matching with any Rajini's movie, it is similar to Nammavar from 1994. Karan was the student, he always made quarrel with Kamal.
The discussion between Kamal and Karan in bathroom is as follows:


 

Thanks!  You successfully identified both movies even though I misidentified the actor in one of them.  I guess I must have conflated Nammavar and Dharmathin Thailavan in my mind (in addition to conflating it with Pandiyan :-)).
